# How to create my wrapper function for library's inline function and pass inline function's type?

Tags: typescript, fastify

I have a simple Fastify route

```
    fastify.post(
      'v1/article',
      {
        schema: {...},
      },
      async (request, reply) => {
        reply.send("ok");
      }
    );
```

I want to create a wrapper for the route handler

```
    fastify.post(
      'v1/article',
      {
        schema: {...},
      },
      myWrapper(async (request, reply) => {
        // type is lost and reply becomes unknown!
        reply.send("ok");
      })
    );
```

This looks simple thing to do but I failed to pass inline function's type to my wrapper's parameter.

I've tried something like below

```
const myWrapper = <RQ, RP>(handler: (req: RQ, rep: RP) => Promise<void>) => {
  return async (req: RQ, rep: RP) => {
    await handler(req, rep);
  };
};
```

But this doesn't work and not passing inline function's type to my wrapper's parameter function... I know what's wrong here but is there any way to solve my issue?

(I can't use types provided from Fastify because I need type inferring from the schema)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're wanting to do is, create a wrapper, wrap your route handler in the wrapper, pass it to the `post` method, and then because you passed it to the `post` methods' handler parameter, you get the types in your wrapper definition (in that particular order), that's not possible. That's not how Typescript works. It needs a context to be able to infer the types, and what you're wanting to do, is just the opposite.

Rather than that, what you can do is create a type that matches the type of the handler parameter in any method, then pass type arguments to the generics' type parameters in that wrapper to get correct inference for schema and all. Then, when you supply your a wrapper, typed with the wrapper type created, to the handler parameter, typescript will error out to let you know that the type of wrapper that you're trying to pass isn't the that's required, per the schema. So, in short, you'll have to provide the types manually there.

[This](https://tsplay.dev/w8VKAm) is how you'd achieve that -

```ts
import Fastify, { RouteHandlerMethod, RouteGenericInterface, FastifyBaseLogger, RawRequestDefaultExpression, RawReplyDefaultExpression, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, FastifySchema, ContextConfigDefault } from 'fastify';

const fastify = Fastify({
    logger: true
});

type Server = typeof fastify.server;

type Wrapper<
    SchemaCompiler extends FastifySchema = FastifySchema,
    ContextConfig = ContextConfigDefault,
    RawServer extends Server = Server,
    RawRequest extends RawRequestDefaultExpression<RawServer> = RawRequestDefaultExpression<RawServer>,
    RawReply extends RawReplyDefaultExpression<RawServer> = RawReplyDefaultExpression<RawServer>,
    RouteGeneric extends RouteGenericInterface = RouteGenericInterface,
    TypeProvider extends FastifyTypeProviderDefault = FastifyTypeProviderDefault,
    Logger extends FastifyBaseLogger = FastifyBaseLogger
> = RouteHandlerMethod<
    RawServer,
    RawRequest,
    RawReply,
    RouteGeneric,
    ContextConfig,
    SchemaCompiler,
    TypeProvider,
    Logger
>;


const handler: Wrapper<{ body: { username: "username", password: "password" } }> = function (
    this,
    // ^? (parameter) this: FastifyInstance<Server<typeof IncomingMessage, typeof ServerResponse>, IncomingMessage, ServerRespons...
    request,
    //  ^? (parameter) this: FastifyInstance<Server<typeof IncomingMessage, typeof ServerResponse>, IncomingMessage, ServerRespons...
    reply) {
    //  ^? (parameter) reply: FastifyReply<Server<typeof IncomingMessage, typeof ServerResponse>, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<...
    reply.send("ok");
}

fastify.post(
    'v1/article/:id',
    {
       schema: {}, 
       // Error: Property 'body' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ body: { username: "username"; password: "password"; }; }
    },
    handler
);
```

Comment: yeah, I know I can do this but I need that specific type from schema inferring.

Comment: hey, I appreciate the answer and the playground link. I know that it needs context to infer the type. I thought that although the wrapper function doesn't have the context but inline function that I inject to the wrapper could have the context. Is there no way to get it work?...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the statement, ***but inline function that I inject to the wrapper could have the context***. Can you elaborate on how that's going to be the case?

Comment: so... in my original post, there is `myWrapper(async (request, reply) => { // here })` the inline function that I'm injecting to `myWrapper` is still inside the scope of fastify handler. That's why I thought there might be some way to get the given type from schema here.

Comment: I see what you mean, it's possible to infer from the return type of the wrapper, like this -

`function wrapper<T>(handler: T): T { return handler; }`

then the types will be inferred for the handler, however, with this, the Typescript will complain about the `schema` parameter, since it has to be statically inferred, and the parameter after is already provided, it complains.

Comment: Let me try and see if I can try and make it not complain about it.

Comment: We can make it not complain about it by providing generic params to `post` method, but then the type in the wrapper becomes `unknown` for the schema. This too is because of the static typing in typescript. When you provide the wrapper param, typescript infers from the return of the wrapper and at that point, type for handler is determined, which is the default type, where the schema is of type `FastifySchema` with all `uknown` types, by providing generic params to `post` we remove the error, but the due to static typing, `request` & `reply` are still same as the default type.

Comment: The best way about it is the way I've provided in my answer.

Comment: Hey, you're right. I must admit it's little far from the ideal I have imagined, though. That seems limitation. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: "Typescript will complain about the schema parameter, since it has to be statically inferred", could you help me to understand what "it has to be statically inferred" means?

Comment: When you provide a wrapper of signature ` function wrapper<T>(handler: T): T { return handler; }`, Typescript has to go to the function definition to infer the type of T, in that type, if you check the lib source, you'll see are type parameter for schema, with a default type value of `FastifySchema` constrained with `FastifySchema`.  With the inference that happened above, for `T` in the wrapper, there's a dependency of schema type parameter, so Typescript goes back to check it's type, and then finds that it's been given a concrete value of some sort, `{ body: { something: 1 } }` for instance.

Comment: With that, it also sees that it's constrained with `FastifySchema` and hence the error - `Type '{ body: { something: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaCompiler'.
  '{ body: { something: number; }; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'SchemaCompiler', but 'SchemaCompiler' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FastifySchema'`. Because Typescript doesn't allow giving a concrete type to a generic _type parameter_.